# En selenium - python no puedo encontrar el elemento li en instagram

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

Estoy programando en python con selenium para seguir automaticamente los seguidores de una cuenta de instagram pero no encuentra la lista de seguidores de la pagina de instagram y no continua con las funciones ya eh intentado cambiarle detalles como la lista , si si la encuentra , agregar para que si no lo encuentra que siga , y asi sucesivamente

Como me esta pidiendo que añada mas detalles voy a escribir hasta que me deje publicar

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('http://instagram.com')
time.sleep(5)


def login():
    user = "user"
    paswd = "password"
    time.sleep(5)
    inputUser = web.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
    inputUser.send_keys(user)
    inputPass = web.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
    inputPass.send_keys(paswd)
    loginButton = web.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]').click()


def open_followers(account_instagram):
    web.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + account_instagram + "/followers/")
    time.sleep(5)


def scroll_followers(minutes):
    print("Estoy en scroll_followers")
    pop_up_window = web.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]')
    # Scroll till Followers list is there
    timeout = time.time() + 60 * minutes
    contador = 0
    while True:
        if time.time() > timeout:
            break
        web.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',pop_up_window)
        follow_followers()
        time.sleep(1)
        contador += 1
        print(contador)
       # dar_click = web.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME , " _acan _acap _acas _aj1- _ap30").click()
       # follow_followers()
       


def follow_followers():
    list_followers = None  # Define la variable antes del bloque try
    
    try:
        print("Estoy en follow_followers")
        list_followers = web.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div')
        print("Encontré la lista")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No se pudo encontrar la lista de seguidores")

    if list_followers is not None:  # Asegúrate de que list_followers tiene un valor antes de intentar iterar sobre él
        for child in list_followers.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li"):
            print("Estoy en el for de ff")
            user_name = child.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".notranslate").text
            follow_button = child.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "button")
            print(user_name)
            print("----")
            print(follow_button.text)
            if "Seguir" == follow_button.text:
                follow_button.click()
                print(user_name + "seguido")
            else:
                print("Ya lo sigues")
            time.sleep(1)
   


sources = ["samuel.cala4"]
login()
time.sleep(5)

for account in sources:
    open_followers(account)
    time.sleep(5)
    scroll_followers(2)
    follow_followers()
```

Ya llevo dos horas intentado y no eh podido , que puede ser ?